# Pull data from web managment interface

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications

Im looking to pull a status field from a web management interface of a UPS so that the data could be utilised in another web application I am writing. I was wondering if anyone would know a way to go about this as I cant seem to find the information I'm looking for through my web searches. Id also need it the value to refresh or re check. Example of UPS web interface below looking at the online field first off:

[image: Example of UPS Web interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic example, that I haven't tested (php isnt installed).

You need to look at the source of your control panel, and find out how to identify the elements that contain your desired information.

The code below (hopefully) searches for an element with an id `server-status` if that element exists it then checks its `class` attribute to determine the state of the server.

You do not have to use the `dom` stuff, you could also do it with regex or whatever. So long as you can accurately find the information you need.

You may also need to use cURL or something a little more advanced than `file_get_contents()` as you will likely require login credentials to view the page in question.

```
<?php

    $html = file_get_contents("http://path.to/your/control.panel");
    // you may need to use cURL or something more advanced if you need to provide login credentials

    $dom = new DOMDocument;

    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $test = $dom->getElementById('server-status');

    if ($test == NULL) {
        // unable to find element, somethings up!
    } else {
        if ($test->getAttribute('class') == "online") {
            // status element has "online" class, server is online
        } else {
            // status element does not have "online" class, somethings up!
        }
    }

?>
```

**Update**

Had a quick look at a demo of that management software and it wont be quite as simple as my example as there don't appear to be any helpful element `id` or `class` names. Its still do-able though.

Comment: Thanks this helps me alot and give me a direction